# How to rotate animate the rotation of a Node in ARCore Sceneform

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I understand that 3D animations such as walking are not yet supported in ARCore, but how can I animate the rotation of a Node?

I know I can set LocalRotation or WorldRotation but how do I make this animated continuously in a smooth fashion?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to use the [Android Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation).  An example of doing this is in the Sceneform sample "Solar System".  Take a look at [RotatingNode](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/RotatingNode.java).  This rotates the node around its axis.

First, it creates an [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) that uses LinearInterpolation to set the rotation between 4 points around a circle.

```
private static ObjectAnimator createAnimator() {
    // Node's setLocalRotation method accepts Quaternions as parameters.
    // First, set up orientations that will animate a circle.
    Quaternion orientation1 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 0);
    Quaternion orientation2 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 120);
    Quaternion orientation3 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 240);
    Quaternion orientation4 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 360);

    ObjectAnimator orbitAnimation = new ObjectAnimator();
    orbitAnimation.setObjectValues(orientation1, orientation2, orientation3, orientation4);

    // Next, give it the localRotation property.
    orbitAnimation.setPropertyName("localRotation");

    // Use Sceneform's QuaternionEvaluator.
    orbitAnimation.setEvaluator(new QuaternionEvaluator());

    //  Allow orbitAnimation to repeat forever
    orbitAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
    orbitAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
    orbitAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    orbitAnimation.setAutoCancel(true);

    return orbitAnimation;
  }
```

Next, it starts the animation:

```
  orbitAnimation = createAnimator();
  orbitAnimation.setTarget(this);
  orbitAnimation.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
  orbitAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Sir, can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437128/how-i-can-set-repeated-texture-on-an-object-in-android-arcore-sceneform-api