# How to rotate a ball.fbx file in augmented reality using android studio?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I am trying to rotate the ball(sfb) asset file in augmented Reality using android studio. i tried some code to rotate the ball by referring the solar system app by google. But i don't know why the ball rotate? i need some suggestion where i did mistake on my code.

```
 private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode transformableNode = new 
        TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        RotatingNode rotatingNode = new RotatingNode();
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode); 
         rotatingNode.setParent(anchorNode);
        rotatingNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        transformableNode.select();
    }
//this is my RotatingNode
private ObjectAnimator createAnimation(){
Quaternion orientation1 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 0);
        Quaternion orientation2 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 120);
        Quaternion orientation3 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 240);
        Quaternion orientation4 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 360);
        ObjectAnimator orbitAnimation = new ObjectAnimator();
        orbitAnimation.setObjectValues(orientation1, orientation2, orientation3, orientation4);
        orbitAnimation.setPropertyName("localRotation");
        orbitAnimation.setEvaluator(new QuaternionEvaluator());
        orbitAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        orbitAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        orbitAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        orbitAnimation.setAutoCancel(true);
        return orbitAnimation;
}
```

i expect the output to rotate the ball but only able to place the ball.

Comment: where did you use this `createAnimation()` function

Comment: check if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396327/6737471

Comment: Thank you for your response.. The code works perfectly.. now the 3d object rotates well..

Comment: glad to hear that